# Jhipster application start fails with JdbcSQLException The object is already closed [90007-190]

Tags: jhipster

I already asked a question about this issue. I tried this on three different databases (H2, MYSQL, Postgre) and two Operating systems. The application works like excpected without custom entities. So I can trace this down to my entity files.

I think it is worth pointing out that I did all the entity generating with the provided generator. I also followed the recommended steps (order of generation of many-to-many, etc.). I am really dont know what to do at this point.

This is the Log (the one for H2 under Windows 10):

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Das Objekt wurde bereits geschlossen
The object is already closed [90007-190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1465) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1443) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.190.jar:1.4.190]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(ConnectionProxy.java:334) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(HikariConnectionProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:361) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted

2016-01-20 22:03:49.020 ERROR 6432 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

This are my entity files:
Game.json

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "frame",
            "otherEntityName": "frame",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "game"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 2,
            "relationshipName": "lane",
            "otherEntityName": "lane",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
            "ownerSide": false,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "game"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 3,
            "relationshipName": "player",
            "otherEntityName": "player",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "ownerSide": false,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "game"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "gameCount",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 2,
            "fieldName": "shotCount",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 3,
            "fieldName": "totalShotCount",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 4,
            "fieldName": "frameCount",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160120203457",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "pagination": "pager"
}
```

Lane.json

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "game",
            "otherEntityName": "game",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "ownerSide": true,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "lane"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "activated",
            "fieldType": "Boolean"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 2,
            "fieldName": "number",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160120203923",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "pagination": "no"
}


{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "lane",
            "otherEntityName": "lane",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "player"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 2,
            "relationshipName": "game",
            "otherEntityName": "game",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "ownerSide": true
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 3,
            "relationshipName": "shot",
            "otherEntityName": "shot",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "player"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "name",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 2,
            "fieldName": "active",
            "fieldType": "Boolean"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160120204127",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "pagination": "pagination"
}
```

Frame.json

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "frame",
            "otherEntityName": "frame",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 2,
            "relationshipName": "player",
            "otherEntityName": "player",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "shotValue",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 2,
            "fieldName": "created",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": 3,
            "fieldName": "shotOrder",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160120204549",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "pagination": "infinite-scroll"
}
```

Frame.json

```
{
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipName": "game",
            "otherEntityName": "game",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 2,
            "relationshipName": "shot",
            "otherEntityName": "shot",
            "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "frame"
        },
        {
            "relationshipId": 3,
            "relationshipName": "player",
            "otherEntityName": "player",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "ownerSide": true
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": 1,
            "fieldName": "frameNumber",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20160120204315",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "no",
    "pagination": "infinite-scroll"
}
```

master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120203457_added_entity_Game.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120203923_added_entity_Lane.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204127_added_entity_Player.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204315_added_entity_Frame.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204549_added_entity_Shot.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase changelogs here -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxx_initial_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120203457_added_entity_Game.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120203923_added_entity_Lane.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204127_added_entity_Player.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204315_added_entity_Frame.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160120204549_added_entity_Shot.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase changelogs here -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxxx_added_entity_Game.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>

    <property name="autoIncrement" value="true" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql,oracle"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Game.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20160120203457" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="game">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="game_count" type="integer"/>
            <column name="shot_count" type="integer"/>
            <column name="total_shot_count" type="integer"/>
            <column name="frame_count" type="integer"/>
        </createTable>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxxx_added_entity_Lane.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>

    <property name="autoIncrement" value="true" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql,oracle"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Lane.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20160120203923" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="lane">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="activated" type="bit"/>
            <column name="number" type="integer"/>
            <column name="game_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints unique="true"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="game_id"
                                 baseTableName="lane"
                                 constraintName="fk_lane_game_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="game"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxxx_added_entity_Player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>

    <property name="autoIncrement" value="true" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql,oracle"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Player.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20160120204127" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="player">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="active" type="bit"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="player_game">
            <column name="games_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="players_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="players_id, games_id" tableName="player_game"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="players_id"
                                 baseTableName="player_game"
                                 constraintName="fk_player_game_game_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="player"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="games_id"
                                 baseTableName="player_game"
                                 constraintName="fk_player_game_player_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="game"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxxx_added_entity_Frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>

    <property name="autoIncrement" value="true" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql,oracle"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Frame.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20160120204315" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="frame">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="frame_number" type="integer"/>
            <column name="game_id" type="bigint"/>
        </createTable>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="game_id"
                                 baseTableName="frame"
                                 constraintName="fk_frame_game_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="game"/>

        <createTable tableName="frame_player">
            <column name="players_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="frames_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="frames_id, players_id" tableName="frame_player"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="frames_id"
                                 baseTableName="frame_player"
                                 constraintName="fk_frame_player_player_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="frame"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="players_id"
                                 baseTableName="frame_player"
                                 constraintName="fk_frame_player_frame_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="player"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

xxxxx_added_entity_Shot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>

    <property name="autoIncrement" value="true" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql,oracle"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Shot.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20160120204549" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="shot">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="shot_value" type="integer"/>
            <column name="created" type="date"/>
            <column name="shot_order" type="integer"/>
            <column name="frame_id" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="player_id" type="bigint"/>
        </createTable>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="frame_id"
                                 baseTableName="shot"
                                 constraintName="fk_shot_frame_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="frame"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="player_id"
                                 baseTableName="shot"
                                 constraintName="fk_shot_player_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="player"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Help would be really appreciated as we would love to build our application on JHipster.